# How to use jQuery with rails webpacker 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I generate a new rails app :

`rails new titi --webpack=vue`

and would like to use jQuery (or other libs like popper, vue-resource...).

I tried to `yarn add jquery`which was fine, but I don't have access to jQuery in my JavaScript code.

In previous Webpacker gem, there was much more conf and I had to write this in `shared.js` :

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [
      ...
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery',
    ]
    ...
    resolve: {
      extensions: settings.extensions,
      modules: [
       resolve(settings.source_path),
        'node_modules'
      ],
      alias: {
        jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
        vue: "vue/dist/vue.js",
        vue_resource: "vue-resource/dist/vue-resource",
    }
}
```

What is the cleanest way to include libraries in current Webpacker version ? Something in `config/webpacker.yml`?

Answer (score 21):

Updated for **Webpacker 3.5.0** and **bootstrap@4.1.1**

`Popper.js` and `bootstrap@4.0.0` aren't required to install JQuery. However, Bootstrap 4 requires both JQuery and Popper.js, and I assume that is the point of showing them in the original example. Also, I omitted Vue from my example as there is ample documentation on how to add the Vue connections.

To get everything to work, I installed `webpack-merge`, `popper.js`, `jquery`, `jquery-ujs`, and `bootstrap@4.1.1` via Yarn.

Once installed, I was able to update `./config/webpack/environment.js` with the following code:

```
/*
  ./config/webpack/environment.js
  Info for this file can be found
  github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md
*/

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const webpack = require('webpack')

// Add an additional plugin of your choosing : ProvidePlugin
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    JQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.Tether': "tether",
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'], // for Bootstrap 4
  })
)

const envConfig = module.exports = environment
const aliasConfig = module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    }
  }
}

module.exports = merge(envConfig.toWebpackConfig(), aliasConfig)
```

Now that `envConfig.toWebpackConfig()` is used in the last statement in `environment.js`, I needed to change `development.js`, `production.js`, `test.js` to the following:

```
const environment = require('./environment')

module.exports = environment
```

Then in `./app/javascript/application.js` I added the following:

```
// ./app/javascript/application.js

/* eslint no-console:0 */
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//
// To reference this file, add <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %> to the appropriate
// layout file, like app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')

// JS libraries
import "jquery"
import "jquery-ujs"
import "bootstrap"
```

To make sure JQuery wasn't being loaded via the asset pipeline, I removed the Rails assets connection in `./app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
// require rails-ujs
// require_tree .
```

I then added these two lines to the `header` section in `./app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` to display the Webpack content:

```
= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application'
= javascript_pack_tag 'application'
```

After making a `static_pages` controller and `static_pages#index` view, after starting the Rails server (`rails s`), I was able to go to my browser's JS console and run `console.log(jQuery().jquery);` to see if JQuery was loading. Everything loaded as expected.

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md

Comment: can you confirm that all that's needed now is `import {} from 'jquery-ujs'` [jquery-ujs readme](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#installation-using-rails-and-webpacke) ?

Comment: Are you asking if just importing the jquery-ujs library alone will make JQuery work in a Rails/Webpack project? `jquery-ujs is the unobtrusive implementation to allow you to use jQuery in a Rails app.` If you look on the doc you cited, the first part of the doc https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs#requirements shows that JQuery is required. I included juery-ujs in this example simply out of habit, as all my previous Rails projects use it as do some of the gems in my projects. If you follow the guide as outlined above, everything will work as expected.

Comment: I'm still not able to access the Popper functions

Comment: @JasonFB interesting. I'm not sure what versions of things you are using. This content is relatively old (almost 3 years). There might be some changes that I'm not aware of that need to be added or removed. You may be able to simply add the popper library in the application.js before you call `import "bootstrap"`, ie `import "popper"`. You'll have to let us know if it works. :-). If I were setting up a Rails app today, I would use Webpack 4; that setup would likely be different that what's found here.

Comment: I am just on the latest version of rails 6.0.2 I think trying to install whatever I can. I did not find a resolution to this problem.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks. That's fine with gem Webpacker 2, but new version of the Gem has a new organisation for files and requires less config.

For Webpack 3, `shared.js` doesn't seem to be mandatory. Instead, I wrote the config in `config/webpack/environment.js` like this :

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

// Add an ProvidePlugin
environment.plugins.set('Provide',  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.Tether': "tether",
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    ActionCable: 'actioncable',
    Vue: 'vue',
    VueResource: 'vue-resource',
  })
)

const config = environment.toWebpackConfig()

config.resolve.alias = {
  jquery: "jquery/src/jquery",
  vue: "vue/dist/vue.js",
  vue_resource: "vue-resource/dist/vue-resource",
}

// export the updated config
module.exports = environment
```

Comment: actually `config.resolve.alias` will not work here, as environment will override default config again.

Comment: Works for me. I tried for about two hours to get Rails UJS to work with my .js.erb files using jQuery and the `config.resolve.alias` part finally did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

@sknight answer is nice. but I add some missing configuration if you have already not include it.

1. create `application.css` file inside `app/javascript/packs/application.css` otherwise you will get the errors like `Webpacker can't find application.css in ~/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:`
2. add `import "./application.css";` in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`
3. add `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";` in `app/javascript/packs/application.js` to use the bootstrap class in your templates

Comment: Thanks for the added info. :-)