# Why is module.export set multiple times?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpacker

In this [Webpacker config](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1432) and [Webpacker setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998003/how-to-use-jquery-with-rails-webpacker-3) there's a common setup:

```js
const envConfig = module.exports = environment

const aliasConfig = module.exports = {...}

module.exports = merge(envConfig.toWebpackConfig(), aliasConfig)
```

What does setting module.exports multiple times do, if anything?

Is this simply a result of people copying/pasting+tweaking code or does it serve a specific mid-file export purpose?

I would like to delete the first two assignments as they appear useless, but I'm not sure if there is a specific effect for Webpack/Webpacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

module.exports just tells what should be exported from this file to be reused in others.

If I just read at what does the 3 lines of code you shared,

`const envConfig = module.exports = environment`

far left-hand side "environment" is assigned to "module.exports"
left-hand side "module.exports" to right-hand side "envConfig"

`const aliasConfig = module.exports = {...}`

"module.exports" is now assigned another object and lost reference to the first object.
"aliasConfig" now references the '{...}' object

`module.exports = merge(envConfig.toWebpackConfig(), aliasConfig)`

"module.exports" is assigned the result of the merge function (if it is using webpack-merge package, this object is a deep merge of the two).
It lost reference to the previous objects.

Declaring module.exports the first times was not necessary.

Webpack config works like any nodejs module.
Here is the link to the documentation on module.exports https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

Also note that using the double assignment syntax can be considered dangerous because of how hoisting works in javascript. If I recall it's easy to create global variables that we don't want/expect that way.

Comment: thanks for that. I understand what the individual lines are doing. Does this create a specific effect for Webpack? To me, it seems like useless assignments so I should only keep the last one, but I don't know JS & Webpack enough to simply delete the first two `module.exports` assignments.

Comment: simple answer is yes delete these assignments. I tried to make a better explanation. you weren't sure about these 3 lines right, so you were not understanding them entirely... and I clearly  made a poor explanation the first time. I hope now it's better. I encourage you to read the you don't know js series